# Message passing in Minix3

Tags: c++, c, minix

I need to write a simple application that sends messages between two processes in Minix. I need some guidance on how to do this. I checked the Minix documentation and it says that only sendrec(src_dst, &message); can be used to send messages and wait for messages on Minix.

I have no idea how to use it in real world so if someone can post a very simple minimal example on how to use this call to send and receive messages, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you know there was a book on Minix? ISBN-13: 978-0131429383 / ISBN-10: 0131429388.

Comment: I have that one but no practical examples are there at all.

Comment: I'm sure you are either trying to write this in C++ or C. Which?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in C

Comment: Then please remove the 'c++' tag

Comment: @Elsban Well, I guess, you haven't spent enough time with the book or the code yet.